# Console broken in old snippets

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-snippets

This is regarding an answer I posted long long ago, so long ago: [Answer: Split string into sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36010000).

When we try adding a snippet, by default, the comment looks like this:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

But for those written long back (see [Answer: Split string into sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36010000)), the snippet has only the following:

```
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

This is not backward compatible as, by default, the console is not shown, thereby, breaking my previous answers, rendering nothing in the preview, where I expect the console be shown.

Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

I'd advice against automatically updating those older snippets.

Those were often written while aware of the fact `console.log` doesn't work. I've seen several workarounds in the past, which would make the added `console.log` redundant on those posts.

At best, it may improve posts that weren't broken in the first place.
At worst, it could break existing posts.

Just edit the post when you see it's necessary.

Comment: Okay, sure... `:)`